# Find 3D position with two point of views

Tags: object, computer-vision, camera, find, position

I'm trying to create a Python script that, given the 2D coordinates (x, y) of an object in two different frames of a video, can determine the 3D position of that object.
I have all the camera data.
I find manuly the objete coordinates in both frames.
I want to achieve this without installing the CV2 library.
I'm not sure why it's not working.
With the following data, I know what the solution have to be, but it doesn't match: The solution should be this vector:
1758.65 1700.01 -62082.2

```
import numpy as np

# Object position on screen in pixels
PA = np.array([1347, 161])
PB = np.array([1332, 310])

# Camera parameters
focal_length = 24 # Focal length in mm
sensor_width = 36.70292659 # Sensor width in mm
sensor_height = 16.05276789 # Sensor height in mm
image_width = 2066 # Image width in pixels
image_height = 904 # Image height in pixels


# Camera A TRS values
translate_A = np.array([41.2077, 1581.17, -58248.5])
rotate_A = np.radians(np.array([12.5716, -10.3674, 5.48064]))
scale_A = np.array([1, 1, 1])

# Transformation matrix of camera A (world matrix)
world_matrix_A = np.array([[0.975436, -0.132941, -0.175646, 41.2077],
                [0.0932196, 0.971563, -0.217659, 1581.17],
                [0.199587, 0.195939, 0.96009, -58248.5],
                [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# Camera B TRS values
translate_B = np.array([71.6219, 1579.81, -57929.7])
rotate_B = np.radians(np.array([8.45298, -10.1539, -4.11146]))
scale_B = np.array([1, 1, 1])

# Transformation matrix of camera B (world matrix)
world_matrix_B = np.array([[0.983663, 0.0447261, -0.174377, 71.6219],
                [-0.070918, 0.986591, -0.146998, 1579.81],
                [0.165465, 0.156963, 0.973645, -57929.7],
                [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# Projection matrix
projection_A = np.array([[focal_length, 0, image_width/2, 0],
                [0, focal_length, image_height/2, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1]])

projection_B = np.array([[focal_length, 0, image_width/2, 0],
                [0, focal_length, image_height/2, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# Normalized 2D points
PA_norm = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(projection_A), np.array([PA[0], PA[1], 1, 1]))
PB_norm = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(projection_B), np.array([PB[0], PB[1], 1, 1]))

# Triangulation
A = np.dot(projection_A, world_matrix_A)
B = np.dot(projection_B, world_matrix_B)

# Get normalized 3D points for each camera
PA_3D = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(A[:3, :3]), -A[:3, 3])  # Get normalized 3D points for each camera A
PB_3D = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(B[:3, :3]), -B[:3, 3])  # Get normalized 3D points for each camera B

# Convert to homogeneous coordinates
PA_3D = np.append(PA_3D, 1)
PB_3D = np.append(PB_3D, 1)

# Get the final 3D position
object_position_3D = (PA_3D[:3] + PB_3D[:3]) / 2

# Print the object position in 3D space
print("Posición del objeto en el espacio 3D:")
print(object_position_3D)
```